# weak variable is intermediately nil

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, weak-references

when are weak variable gets nil?

```
    weak var backgroundNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(image: initialBackgroundImage!))
    backgroundNode!.position = CGPoint(x: rootSkScene!.frame.midX, y: rootSkScene!.frame.midY)
```

getting always:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

[Xcode error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1ySH.png)

Comment: ***why*** are you using a weak pointer? of course it will crash, the object gets released immediately after assigning and therefore be `nil` when you come to unwrap it. I suggest you have a read up on the ARC docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html

Comment: so what would be a use case for weak variables?

Comment: well, when you don't want the pointer to retain the object in memory, for example a delegate object. they can also be used in some cases to prevent a retain cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So weak variable means that this reference isn't increasing counter of references by one. As you know if counter equals zero object will be deleted. What you are doing here that - you are creating variable but as it is weak it has counter equals zero and it destroys. Also because it is weak - when it destroys its reference will automatically become nil value.

So what we gets is that in first line you create object and it immediately destroys and reference becomes nil. In second line you tried to do some work with this variable but as it's nil you gets such exception. Hope it helped you.

To fix this bug just remove first line of code with

```
let backgroundNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(image: initialBackgroundImage!))
```

Comment: thank you, i know that this would be working. Didn't understand the meaning of weaks....

Comment: Deleting in iOS works with counting references. So when you perform operation like this 

ref = someObjects; 

counter for some object increases with one. When your reference are out of your possible working space(for example function ends) - counter decreasing with one. If counter becomes equal zero - object deletes. That how it works for standard references. Week reference doesn't interacts with counter and wont increase or decrease counter. Thats why your object created with counter = 0 doesn't increased it and was deleted on the next step. For simple(strong) reference it would increase.

Answer (score 3):

Local variables should pretty much always be strong. That way if you create an object and save it to a local variable, the strong reference provided by the local variable keeps the object alive. When you exit the current scope, the local variable is popped off the stack and it's strong reference goes away.

In your code, the `SKSpriteNode` `initWithTexture` method creates a new sprite kit node and returns it. At the point the function returns, the init function no longer has a strong reference to the object. You save the result of the `initWithTexture` call to a weak variable, so at the end of that statement, there are **NO** strong references to the object. It gets released immediately. That is why it becomes nil.

Solution: change your local variable to strong. Change:

```
weak var backgroundNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(image: initialBackgroundImage!))
```

to

```
var backgroundNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(image: initialBackgroundImage!))
```

Comment: so when you have IBOutlets created as `weak`, they don't get deallocated immediately. What's keeping them in memory? What's holding a strong reference to them? The storyboard?

Comment: An object needs at least one owning/strong reference to it in order to stay alive. When views get created by the storyboard they get put into the view hierarchy. Each view owns it's subviews, and the view controller owns the main content view.