# Not able to decode value in a weak variable

Tags: ios, swift4, codable

```
class User: Codable {

//MARK:- Properties
var firstName: String?
var lastName: String?
weak var friend: User?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case firstName = "first"
    case lastName = "last"
    case friend
}
```

}

The User class has a friend property which will again be of type User. So in order to avoid any retain cycles, i have taken it as weak variable. But when the JSONDecoder decodes the json then the friend property of the user instance is always nil. If i am wrong in taking the friend as weak in this context?. if it is correct then how the value will be inserted in the friend property of the User.

Also read this [weak variable is intermediately nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35091284/weak-variable-is-intermediately-nil). Will there be any retain cycles if i donot use weak?

Comment: why your variable is weak? must be strong, without weak by default

Comment: Won't there be any retain cycles if friend is of type Strong? Since User has the string reference to friend and also friend has the strong reference to the User.

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: @ReinierMelian thanks, i am clear now about the retain cycles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your friend variable must be strong in this context, if not then will be instantiated and deallocated once your init with coder method ends, change `weak var friend: User?` by this `var friend: User?`

about retain cycles, you will get a retain cycle only if `self.friend.friend = self` or `self.friend = self`

you can always check if an object is getting deallocated implementing `deinit` method

**Examples**

**case1**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var user1 : User?
    var user2 : User?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        user1 = User()

        user2 = User()
        user1?.friend = user2

        user1 = nil
    }
```

**Result**

> user1 deallocated

**case2**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
        var user1 : User?
        var user2 : User?
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

            user1 = User()
            user1?.friend = user1

            user1 = nil
        }
```

**Result**

> user1 don't deallocated -> Retain Cycle Issue