# Dismissing ViewController doesn't deallocate memory in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, memory, uiviewcontroller

I have a viewcontroller (lets called it TableViewController). When user taps a button inside custom UITableViewCell, a new view controller (lets called it DetailViewcontroller) is opening. When user tap back button inside DetailViewController, I called dismiss function and TableViewController opens again.

My problem is that when I do this scenario like 50 times, memory usage gets higher. So I guess It doesn't do any deallocation.

[image: Memory Usage]

How I opens DetailViewController;

```
    @objc func voteBtnTapped(_ sender: UIButton){
    guard let team = FirebaseManager.instance.currentTeam else { return }
    FirebaseManager.instance.delegate = nil
    let voteController = VoteViewController()
    voteController.currentTeam = team
    let transition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 0.5
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight
    transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
    self.present(voteController, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

How I dismiss DetailViewController;

```
    @objc func backBtnTapped(_ sender: UIButton){
    FirebaseManager.instance.delegate = nil
    let transition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 0.5
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft
    transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
    self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

It says leaks in Instruments but I can't figure out, what cause these leeks.

[image]

EDIT: I found that the picker library I'm using (in DetailViewController), blocks deallocation. Do you have any idea why It blocks it and how can I handle it?

From respond to answer how I declare pickerView:

```
 let config = AZAPickerConfiguration<PickerItem>(items: (1...10).map { PickerItem(number: $0) },
                                                    defaultSelectedIndex: 4,
                                                    selectedFont: UIFont(name: "SourceSansPro-SemiBold", size: 50)!, nonSelectedFont:UIFont(name: "SourceSansPro-Light", size: 20)!, selectionRadiusInPercent: 0.5,
                                                    selectionBackgroundColor: UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.42, blue:0.20, alpha:1.0), itemWidth: 80)

    self.pickerView = AZAPicker<PickerItem>(with: config, frame: .zero)

    pickerView!.backgroundColor = .white
    pickerView!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    //self.pickerView!.onPickItem = self.picker
    self.pickerView!.onPickItem = {( sender : AZAPicker<PickerItem>,item:PickerItem) in
        print("didPickItem: \(item)")
        self.currentPoint = item.number

    }
```

https://github.com/AvanzaBank/AZAPicker

Comment: please use `Instruments` and allocation tool and show us what is allocating this memory

Comment: I added. Can you please check It? @Lu_

Comment: Do you reuse cells in tableview? it is all a string allocation, you need to find where in code this is allocated this many times

Comment: can you show CellForRowAtIndexPath code ?

Comment: I added @Pandey_Laxman

Comment: @EmreÖnder cellForRowAtIndexPath code looks Ok, Can you plz check in your code somewhere you are holding strong reference for of TableViewController Either in Delegate or in property, may be voteController's closure capturing self, becuase deinit is not calling of VoteController that's the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That Library seems to have an error in the use form, in the example code is declared a method like this

```
func picker(sender: AZAPicker<PickerItem>, item: PickerItem) {
    print("didPickItem: \(item)")
}
```

but instead of doing that you need to assign a closure in this way and **problem solved**!

**UPDATED (in your code)**

```
self.pickerView!.onPickItem = {[weak self]( sender : AZAPicker<PickerItem>,item:PickerItem) in
    print("didPickItem: \(item)")
    self.currentPoint = item.number

}
```

**Full Code Reference**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func dismiss(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let config = AZAPickerConfiguration<PickerItem>(items: (1...100).map { PickerItem(number: $0) },
                                           defaultSelectedIndex: 99,
                                           selectionRadiusInPercent: 0.5,
                                           itemWidth: 80)

        let pickerView = AZAPicker<PickerItem>(with: config, frame: .zero)

        pickerView.backgroundColor = .white
        //in this code [weak self] is not needed because I don't use self inside the closure
        pickerView.onPickItem = {( sender : AZAPicker<PickerItem>,item:PickerItem) in
            print("didPickItem: \(item)")
        }

        pickerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(pickerView)

        NSLayoutConstraint(item: pickerView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: topLayoutGuide, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 20).isActive = true

        NSLayoutConstraint(item: pickerView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true

        NSLayoutConstraint(item: pickerView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true

        NSLayoutConstraint(item: pickerView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 80).isActive = true
    }

}
```

Comment: Where do I need to write this one? in viewdidload?

Comment: where you have  `pickerView.onPickItem = self.picker`@EmreÖnder you can also remove the function declaration

Comment: I put it inside viewdidload and delete old declaration and function. Completion works but still not deallocating.

Comment: I add how I declare the PickerView

Comment: Once you reference self in the closure, you end up with the same leak issue again. In that case you need to pass in a [weak self] capture list.

The problem might still persist as their delegate property is a strong reference ... has to be weak, or needs to be set to nil at some point before intentionally deallocating.

Comment: @MartinM I am not referencing self in the closure so, [weak self] is not needed, about the delegate changing it to weak don't solve the issue

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you! @ReinierMelian I'll be happy if u give plus vote to question :)

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that *detailViewController* is the object causing the leak.

```
deinit {
 print("detailViewController deallocated")
}
```

if deinit is not called then there is a strong reference keeping *detailsViewController* alive. Check if you have closures inside *detailViewController* where you use self without having a weak reference. or somewhere where you keep a reference of *detailViewController* in *TableViewController*.

Comment: I wrote it inside detailViewController class but It doesn't called.

Comment: @EmreÖnder normally this can be caused by 3 things, 1- a delegate that is declared as strong, a closure without [weak self] and 3 another viewController holding a strong reference of this viewController and this viewController holding a strong reference to that viewController check this answer maybe can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49814852/not-able-to-decode-value-in-a-weak-variable/49815043#49815043

Comment: I edit my question. Can you please check it? @ReinierMelian

Comment: @EmreÖnder you are right is I will rise an issue on github repo and push the solution for this

Comment: I opened a issue but actually don't have enough time for this. I rather delete the library and write a new one myself or find solution. I already try to change delegation in library to weak var from var but doesn't worked. Can you please check the source code? If u can find something :) Thank you.

Comment: @EmreÖnder I had fixed the issue I will post the answer here